# OpenGL - drawing objects using text file

Tags: c++, opengl

I have loaded an array from a text file, which contains positions of objects, and it looks like this:

```
0,0,0,5
0,5,0,0
0,0,5,0
0,5,5,0
```

The object looks like this:

```
struct object
{
    int x, y, value;
}
```

Where x,y are coordinates, and value is 1 or 0 (it tells if an object was "picked", all objects have 1 at the beginning). Objects are stored in an array `object obj_array[5]`.

To draw them, I use this function:
(BOARD_Y and BOARD_Y is size of the array, here is 4x4)

```
void draw_board(){

    for (int iy = 0; iy < BOARD_Y; iy++) {      
        for (int ix = 0; ix < BOARD_X; ix++) {

            if ( (board[iy][ix] == 5) )
            {
                glPushMatrix();                 
                glTranslatef( ix, iy, 0 );
                glutSolidCube(1);
                glPopMatrix();  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it draws all of them perfectly. But I want to skip drawing an object, if its value is 0 (the object was picked by a player). How can I do this?

Comment: It might be worth looking into the [Wavefront OBJ format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file). It's a very simple format, but it's got quite a lot of features, as well as a lot of existing loaders/parsers

Comment: Where are your `object`s stored?

Comment: @Bojangles I think the title has tricked you - this has nothing to do with reading models from files. The file here is a board of objects.

Comment: maybe add another if-statement to your loop?

Comment: @sftrabbit I need to start reading things, don't I `:(`

Comment: Objects are stored in an array. I made some if statements, but it resulted in all objects somehow disappearing. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `board` is a text file containing coordinates for objects.

Comment: No. `board` is a variable. What type does it have?

Comment: `board`'s type is `int**`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I can see what's going on; you've complicated the things a bit. There's no way to access the arbitrary object just from this loop, apart from pretty stupid comparison of position:

```
if ( (board[iy][ix] == 5) ) {
    for (auto const& obj : objects) {
        if (obj.x == ix && obj.y == iy) {
            // obj is the object in given position
            // ...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Don't** do that.

Instead either store some reference to the objects on the board. By reference I mean (not limited to!):

- An unique object ID
- Pointer to the object

Then, you will be able to access the object residing on given tile much faster and easier. If you want examples, drop a comment, but I think both options are fairly easy to implement.

If you still want to hold these "5" inside, change board to array of structs. And oh, *please* use `std::array` instead of `int**`.

Here's the example

```
using id_t = unsigned;

std::map<id_t, object> objects;

constexpr std::size_t size_x = 4, size_y = 4;
std::array<id_t, size_x * size_y> board;
```

Let's assume that `id` equal to 0 means that the object is not there.
Now you can access the specific object by:

```
unsigned x, y;

id_t obj_id = board[x + size_x * y];

if (obj_id != 0) // is there any object?
    if (objects[obj_id].value != 0) // is its value equal to 0?
        // ...
```

And set it by `board[...] = obj;`

Easy way to generate unique id for every object is just to increment the counter.

```
id_t last_id = 1;
objects[last_id++] = obj_id;
```